# Laravel where clause not working after series of orwhere

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a query that fetches users based on some parameters.

```
$users = User::where(function($query) use($queryTags_userIDs) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $queryTags_userIDs);
})->orWhere(function($query) use($queryImageTitles_userIDs) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $queryImageTitles_userIDs);
})->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")     
    ->orWhere('profile_text', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->orWhere('tagline', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->where('role', 2)
    ->orderBy('last_login', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Now, this whole thing works great.

Except this part:

```
->where('role', 2)
```

Instead of getting users where role is 2, it fetches users of EVERY role.

However, it WILL work if I get rid of some orWheres.

If I get rid of these 3 orWheres:

```
->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")     
->orWhere('profile_text', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
->orWhere('tagline', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
```

then it starts fetching users only with role 2. In fact, these 3 specific orWheres are, for whatever reason, causing the problem

If I reduce the query to only

```
$users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")     
    ->where('role', 2)
    ->orderBy('last_login', 'desc')
    ->paginate(7);
```

it STILL gets users from outside of role 2.

However, if it were to switch it to this:

```
$users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->where('role', 2)
    ->orderBy('last_login', 'desc')
    ->paginate(7);
```

then all of a sudden it only gets users from role 2.

Why is this happening? I feel like I'm missing something super obvious, because this makes no sense.

**EDIT**

In response to Bassem El Hachem, I put role = 2 at the beginning of the query. But it still doesn't work. Here is the query after the change:

> "select * from `users` where `role` = ? and (`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?)) or (`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)) or (`username` LIKE ? or `keywords` LIKE ? or
>   `profile_text` LIKE ? or `tagline` LIKE ?) order by `last_login` desc"

Comment: Try my new answer. The other `WHERE` are all `OR`s or is there another mandatory WHERE?

Comment: New answer works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your query in SQL is this:

```
WHERE keywords like '%...%' OR profile_text LIKE '%...%' 
OR tagline LIKE '%...%' AND role=2
```

The `AND` operator in SQL is like multiplication, it adds a parenthesis which means your query is really:

```
WHERE keywords like '%...%' OR profile_text LIKE '%...%' 
OR (tagline LIKE '%...%' AND role=2)
```

So the filter `role=2` is being applied **to specific rows only** (the ones where `tagline LIKE '%...%'`). For rows where `keywords like '%...%' OR profile_text LIKE '%...%'`, role can be any value, which is not what you want.

What you need to do is apply the filtering WHERE on `role` directly on `user`. This also helps with efficiency undoubtably.

```
$users = User::where('role', 2)
  ->where(function($q) use($queryTags_userIDs,$queryImageTitles_userIDs,$query) {
      $q->whereIn('id', $queryTags_userIDs)
      ->orWhereIn('id', $queryImageTitles_userIDs)
      ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
      ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")     
      ->orWhere('profile_text', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
      ->orWhere('tagline', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%");
   })->orderBy('last_login', 'desc')
   ->paginate(15);
```

Since it's not clear what result you want, I would suggest to view the query in SQL syntax. This can be done by replacing `paginate(15)` by `toSql()` and `dd()` the results.